# How to get Sorted alphabetical markers

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

The code in the fiddle below has 3 Fixed Locations. An address can then be inputted and the distance from that address to all three Fixed Locations will be calculated. The results are then sorted in order by distance in a sidebar on the right.

I'm trying to figure out how to assign lettered markers for each result. So each time the results are calculated, the first closest marker would be letter A, the second closest marker would be letter B and so on. I'd also like the letter A to appear in the sidebar next to the first closest result and letter B to appear in the sidebar next to the second closest results and so on.

I haven't been able to find any instructions how to do this?  Can anyone help?

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vj0cpv0c/2/

```
var locations = [
  ["John Doe", "145 Rock Ridge Road, Chester, NY ", "41.314926,-74.270134", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
  ["Jim Smith", "12 Williams Rd, Montvale, NJ ", "41.041599,-74.019554", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
  ["John Jones", "689 Fern St Township of Washington, NJ ", "40.997704,-74.050598", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png"],
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself, not (only) a link to an external site like jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

What you where looking for was `.set('label', letterMarkers);` using int to char we can turn 0 into A, 1 into B and place this onto the markers and list.

in function `calculateDistances` you work out and sort the pins, which we can then draw the letters on, I also added the letter above the link in the right list

you should now see a,b,c in the list on the right
and pins in a,b,c order from distance

code changed:

```
    closest[i].setMap(map);       
    var letterMarkers = String.fromCharCode(97 + i);
    closest[i].set('label', letterMarkers);
    outputDiv.innerHTML += letterMarkers + " <br>
```

all code:

```js
var locations = [
  ["John Doe", "145 Rock Ridge Road, Chester, NY ", "41.314926,-74.270134", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
  ["Jim Smith", "12 Williams Rd, Montvale, NJ ", "41.041599,-74.019554", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
  ["John Jones", "689 Fern St Township of Washington, NJ ", "40.997704,-74.050598", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png"],

];
// alert(locations.length);

var geocoder = null;
var map = null;
var customerMarker = null;
var gmarkers = [];
var closest = [];
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  // alert("init");
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 9,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.6699927, -0.7274620),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker, i;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "found " + locations.length + " locations<br>";
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var coordStr = locations[i][2];
    var coords = coordStr.split(",");
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]), parseFloat(coords[1]));
    bounds.extend(pt);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pt,
      map: map,
      icon: locations[i][3],
      address: locations[i][1],
      title: locations[i][0],
      html: locations[i][0] + "<br>" + locations[i][1] + "<br><br><a href='javascript:getDirections(customerMarker.getPosition(),&quot;" + locations[i][1] + "&quot;);'>Get Directions</a>"
    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })
      (marker, i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      if (customerMarker) customerMarker.setMap(null);
      customerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
      closest = findClosestN(results[0].geometry.location, 12);
      // get driving distance
      closest = closest.splice(0, 12);
      calculateDistances(results[0].geometry.location, closest, 12);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function findClosestN(pt, numberOfResults) {
  var closest = [];
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "processing " + gmarkers.length + "<br>";
  for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
    gmarkers[i].distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pt, gmarkers[i].getPosition());
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "process " + i + ":" + gmarkers[i].getPosition().toUrlValue(6) + ":" + gmarkers[i].distance.toFixed(2) + "<br>";
    gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
    closest.push(gmarkers[i]);
    closest.sort(sortByDist);
  }

  return closest;
}

function sortByDist(a, b) {
  return (a.distance - b.distance)

}

function calculateDistances(pt, closest, numberOfResults) {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  var request = {
    origins: [pt],
    destinations: [],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < closest.length; i++) {
    request.destinations.push(closest[i].getPosition());
  }
  service.getDistanceMatrix(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
      var origins = response.originAddresses;
      var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('side_bar');
      outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

      var results = response.rows[0].elements;
      // save title and address in record for sorting
      for (var i = 0; i < closest.length; i++) {
        results[i].title = closest[i].title;
        results[i].address = closest[i].address;
        results[i].idx_closestMark = i;
      }
      results.sort(sortByDistDM);
      for (var i = 0;
        ((i < numberOfResults) && (i < closest.length)); i++) {
        closest[i].setMap(map);       
        var letterMarkers = String.fromCharCode(97 + i);
        closest[i].set('label', letterMarkers);
        outputDiv.innerHTML += letterMarkers + " <br><a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(closest[" + results[i].idx_closestMark + "],\"click\");'>" + results[i].title + '</a><br>' + results[i].address + "<br>" + results[i].distance.text + ' approximately ' + results[i].duration.text + "<br><a href='javascript:getDirections(customerMarker.getPosition(),&quot;" + results[i].address + "&quot;);'>Get Directions</a><br><hr>"
        
        
       

      }
    }
  });
}

function getDirections(origin, destination) {
  var request = {
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('side_bar'));
    }
  });
}

function sortByDistDM(a, b) {
  return (a.distance.value - b.distance.value)
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
table,tr,td {
  height: 100%;
  }


.text {
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="map" style="height: 100%; width:400px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="side_bar" class='text'> </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input id="address" type="text" value="Paramus, NJ" />
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="codeAddress();" />
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: It almost works!!  The sidebar results are sorted and alphabetized by Google Mileage like I want but the letters on the map are alphabetized by straight line mileage which isn't what I want.  Any fix for this?  Thanks so much for the help!!!

Comment: Why do you say they are ordered by straight line distance?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates that issue (including the marker data and the search address).  As far as I can tell they are sorted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up,sorted pins I used general javascript to make closest match results, there may be a better way of doing this with the API.

added code:

```
 var pins = [];     

 results.forEach(function(result){
    closest.forEach(function (addr){    
        if(result.address === addr.address){         
        pins.push(addr);
      }
    });
 });
```

and used pins[i] instead of closest in the for loop.

all code:

```js
 var locations = [
  ["John Doe", "29 Buhl Lane, East Northport, NY ", "40.858924, -73.297327", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
  ["Jim Smith", "12 Williams Rd, Montvale, NJ ", "41.041599,-74.019554", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
  ["John Jones", "689 Fern St Township of Washington, NJ ", "40.997704,-74.050598", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png"],

];
// alert(locations.length);

var geocoder = null;
var map = null;
var customerMarker = null;
var gmarkers = [];
var closest = [];
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  // alert("init");
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 9,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.6699927, -0.7274620),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker, i;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "found " + locations.length + " locations<br>";
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var coordStr = locations[i][2];
    var coords = coordStr.split(",");
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]), parseFloat(coords[1]));
    bounds.extend(pt);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pt,
      map: map,
      icon: locations[i][3],
      address: locations[i][1],
      title: locations[i][0],
      html: locations[i][0] + "<br>" + locations[i][1] + "<br><br><a href='javascript:getDirections(customerMarker.getPosition(),&quot;" + locations[i][1] + "&quot;);'>Get Directions</a>"
    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })
      (marker, i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  $("#mdiv").click(function() {
    $("#side_bar").css({
      "z-index": 100,
      "top": "0px"
    });
    $("#panel").css("z-index", -100);
    $("#mdiv").css("display", "none");
  })

}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      if (customerMarker) customerMarker.setMap(null);
      customerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
      closest = findClosestN(results[0].geometry.location, 12);
      // get driving distance
      closest = closest.splice(0, 12);
      calculateDistances(results[0].geometry.location, closest, 12);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function findClosestN(pt, numberOfResults) {
  var closest = [];
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "processing " + gmarkers.length + "<br>";
  for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
    gmarkers[i].distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pt, gmarkers[i].getPosition());
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "process " + i + ":" + gmarkers[i].getPosition().toUrlValue(6) + ":" + gmarkers[i].distance.toFixed(2) + "<br>";
    gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
    closest.push(gmarkers[i]);
    closest.sort(sortByDist);
  }

  return closest;
}

function sortByDist(a, b) {
  return (a.distance - b.distance)

}

function calculateDistances(pt, closest, numberOfResults) {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  var request = {
    origins: [pt],
    destinations: [],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < closest.length; i++) {
    request.destinations.push(closest[i].getPosition());
  }
  service.getDistanceMatrix(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
      var origins = response.originAddresses;
      var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('side_bar');
      outputDiv.innerHTML = '';
   
      var results = response.rows[0].elements;
      // save title and address in record for sorting
      for (var i = 0; i < closest.length; i++) {
        results[i].title = closest[i].title;
        results[i].address = closest[i].address;
        results[i].idx_closestMark = i;
      }
      
     results.sort(sortByDistDM);    
     
     var pins = [];     
        
     results.forEach(function(result){
        closest.forEach(function (addr){    
         if(result.address === addr.address){         
           pins.push(addr);
          }
        });
     });      
    
      for (var i = 0;
        ((i < numberOfResults) && (i < closest.length)); i++) {
        pins[i].setMap(map);       
        var letterMarkers = String.fromCharCode(97 + i);
        pins[i].set('label', letterMarkers);
        outputDiv.innerHTML += letterMarkers + " <br><a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(closest[" + results[i].idx_closestMark + "],\"click\");'>" + results[i].title + '</a><br>' + results[i].address + "<br>" + results[i].distance.text + ' approximately ' + results[i].duration.text + "<br><a href='javascript:getDirections(customerMarker.getPosition(),&quot;" + results[i].address + "&quot;);'>Get Directions</a><br><hr>"
        
    
      }
    }
  });
}

function getDirections(origin, destination) {
  var request = {
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      $("#side_bar").css({
        "z-index": -100,
        "top": "25px"
      });
      $("#panel").css("z-index", 100);
      $("#mdiv").css("display", "block");

      directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));


    }
  });
}

function sortByDistDM(a, b) {
  return (a.distance.value - b.distance.value)
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
 html,
 body,
 #map {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 600px;
   width: 400px;
 }
 
 .text {
   width: 300px;
   height: 600px;
   background-color: white;
   overflow: scroll;
   overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
 }
 
 #side_bar {
   z-index: 100;
   position: absolute;
   top: 135px;
   left: 400px;
 }
 
 #panel {
   z-index: -100;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 135px;
   left: 400px;
 }
 
 #mdiv {
   z-index: 500;
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   display: none;
   background-color: red;
   border: 1px solid black;
   position: absolute;
   left: 660px;
   top: 112px;
 }
 
 .mdiv {
   height: 25px;
   width: 2px;
   margin-left: 12px;
   background-color: black;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
   /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
   /* Safari and Chrome */
   z-index: 1;
 }
 
 .md {
   height: 25px;
   width: 2px;
   background-color: black;
   transform: rotate(90deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
   /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
   /* Safari and Chrome */
   z-index: 2;
 }
 
 tr:nth-child(even) {
   background: #CCC
 }
 
 tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background: #FFF
 }
```

```html
<div class="bh-sl-container">
  <div id="page-header">
    <h1 class="bh-sl-title">The Auditor Locator</h1>

  </div>

  <div class="bh-sl-form-container">
    <form id="bh-sl-user-location" method="post" action="#">
      <div class="form-input">
        <label for="bh-sl-address">Enter Address or Zip Code:</label>
        <input id="address" type="text" value="Danbury, CT" />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="codeAddress();" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <table border="0" style="height:100%">
    <tr style="height:100%">
      <td style="height:100%">
        <div id="map"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="side_bar" class='text'></div>
        <div id="panel" class='text'></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <div id="info"></div>
  <div id="mdiv">
    <div class="mdiv">
      <div class="md">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```